What is the difference between "Bachelorstudiengang" and "Bachelor-Studium"?
What is the difference between "Bachelorstudiengang" and "Bachelor-Studium"?
In which context, the above mentioned words are fitting.
For example:
What should be the correct translation for the following phrases?

"Application to Bachelor's degree ..."
"After completing my Bachelor's degree ..."
"During my Bachelor's program ..."


Conceptually, all of your class mates pursue the same Studiengang (classes, requirements, grading procedures etc.), but each one has their own Studium (assignments, grades etc.). You can pretty much apply for either to express the same intent.

Bachelor-Studium describes studying towards a Bachelor degree, whatever the subject may be. The focus is on the act of studying and the degree you are trying to achieve, contrasting the Bachelor for example with a Master or a Diploma. It can be combined with a possessive pronoun to indicate the status of the named person as a student.
Bachelorstudiengang describes a specific field of study, and will almost always be followed by the discipline, as in der Bachelorstudiengang Informatik (Bachelor of Computer Science) or der Bachelorstudiengang Erziehungswissenschaft (Bachelor in Education). The focus is on the program and the progression (Gang) of courses you will have to take until you reach the degree. Combining it with a possessive pronoun is quite unusual, as that would focus the individual program the person is following in contrast to what everyone else doing.
For your examples, some may need to be completed to full sentences to make the choice unambiguous:

"Application to a Bachelor's degree in German Literature": Bewerbung für den Bachelorstudiengang Deutsche Literatur
"An application to a Bachelor's degree requires the applicant to prove all needed qualifications": Eine Bewerbung für ein Bachelor-Studium erfordert den Nachweis aller notwendigen Qualifikationen durch den Bewerber.
"After completing my Bachelor's degree I entered a Master's program at Potsdam University": Here, the verb "complete" calls for a focus on the passing of the exam, the "Abschluss": Nach dem Erreichen des Bachelor-Abschlusses begann ich ein Master-Studium an der Universität Potsdam.
"During my Bachelor's program I had to work for my living": Während meines Bachelor-Studiums musste ich für meinen Lebensunterhalt arbeiten.

An example for "mein Studiengang" could be

"My Bachelor's program in Physics was individually tailored because my previous courses in Mathematics were accredited.": Mein Bachelorstudiengang Physik wurde individuell zusammengestellt, da meine früheren Mathematik-Kurse anerkannt wurden.

